# MySQL: Proper way to use transactions, GET DIAGNOSTICS, & SQLEXCEPTION SET in a Stored Procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, transactions, commit, rollback

I am trying to create a Stored Procedure in MySQL use transactions to either capture errors, display them, & rollback OR commit if no errors.  This what I have come up with.  It is not displaying the error or why the transaction has failed.  Any suggestions?

```
Delimiter //

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS TMP_SP_RunSQL //
CREATE PROCEDURE TMP_SP_RunSQL()
SP: BEGIN
        
       DECLARE `_rollback` BOOL DEFAULT 0;
       DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION SET `_rollback` = 1;

        /* Check Current Version of DB */
        IF TRUE THEN

         START TRANSACTION;


            /* This should cause an error. The `test` column has already been dropped */
            ALTER TABLE `Test`
              DROP COLUMN `test`;

        
            IF `_rollback` THEN
                GET DIAGNOSTICS CONDITION 1 @errorMessage = MESSAGE_TEXT;
                SELECT @errorMessage AS Message;
                SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = @errorMessage;
                
                ROLLBACK;
                
                SELECT 'The database update failed' AS Message;
                
            ELSE
                COMMIT;
            
                SELECT 'The database update succeeded' AS Message;
            END IF;
        
        ELSE
            SELECT 'TMP_FN_CheckLkpVersion failed' AS Message;

        END IF;

END // 

DELIMITER ;


CALL TMP_SP_RunSQL();

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS TMP_SP_RunSQL;
```

I created the above procedure to GET DIAGNOSTICS CONDITION and put in it a variable called  @errorMessage then display that variable.

I was expecting to see:  ***Error 1091, Can't Drop 'Test'; check that column / key exists.***

Comment: Check [13.3.3 Statements That Cause an Implicit Commit](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/implicit-commit.html). See [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/QaxBp3Vb) without transaction.